# Django Queryset: Efficiency of Equivalent Filter Clauses

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

Why applying several arguments in one filter clause is not equivalent to multiple calls of filter for each argument?

I have **Blog** and **Comment** models.

Evaluation of this query takes several minutes:

```
Blog.objects.filter(comment__created__gt=from).filter(comment__created__lt=till)
```

While evaluation time for this one is less then a second:

```
Blog.objects.filter(comment__created__gt=from, comment__created__lt=till)
```

**Update** My models.py:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    pass

class Comment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Blog')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I use Django 1.4.5.

Comment: why are you deleting your posts and asking the same question again ?

Comment: It would prove very helpful if you included your code for models.py

Comment: Sorry karthikr, I have made mistake in my previous question. Problem occurs only when filter argument contains foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's look at the sql for each query:

for this example, I used `now = till = from_dt = datetime.now()` just for example purposes. Also, **never use from as a variable name**. If you're surprised or asking why then stop everything you're doing and start learning basic python. Anyway:

```
In [6]: query1 = Blog.objects.filter(comment__created__gt=from_dt).filter(comment__created__lt=till)

In [7]: print query1.query
SELECT "myapp_blog"."id", "myapp_blog"."name" 
FROM "myapp_blog" 

    INNER JOIN "myapp_comment" 
    ON ("myapp_blog"."id" = "myapp_comment"."blog_id") 

    INNER JOIN "myapp_comment" T3 
    ON ("myapp_blog"."id" = T3."blog_id") 

WHERE ("myapp_comment"."created" > 2013-12-15 15:54:50.633000  
AND T3."created" < 2013-12-15 15:54:50.633000 )
```

Well look at that. How many joins!
Now let's take a loo

```
In [10]: query2 = Blog.objects.filter(comment__created__gt=from_dt, comment__created__lt=till)
In [11]: print query2.query
SELECT "myapp_blog"."id", "myapp_blog"."name" 
FROM "myapp_blog" 

    INNER JOIN "myapp_comment" 
    ON ("myapp_blog"."id" = "myapp_comment"."blog_id") 

WHERE ("myapp_comment"."created" > 2013-12-15 15:54:50.633000  
AND "myapp_comment"."created" < 2013-12-15
15:54:50.633000 )
```

See? It's half the work. That's because you're filtering *on a relationship*, (you probably wouldn't see such an effect on fields of the same object you are filtering on) so by adding up the filters, you need to run through the joins twice ,just for fetching the data from the related model.

In other words - Each time you filter on a related model, you need another join, so with two filters you get two joins, with one you only get one join. If this was a ManyToMany relationship that would be **double** because you'd have a third table. Does this help clear things up?

Comment: Thanks. So when filtering by relashinship, I should always use Blog.objects.filter(**q). Also, thanks for the tip about variable nameing, I used "from" only in the question (;

Comment: yes, filtering on a related model is always costly so you should always be mindful and economic as much as you can. happy to have helped!